# Get unique values from a for loop by filtering duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Goal**: I want to get a list of values which are unique. The list should remove duplicates and ideally should order them based on number

I have the following JSON file.

```
{ "words" : [{"id":598,"tags":[104,65],"langs":[1]},{"id":597,"tags":[104,65],"langs":[1]},{"id":596,"tags":[20,30],"langs":[1]}]}
```

Within my script I have the following code:

```
count = 0
tags = []
for index in data['words']: 
    count += 1
    tags.append(index["tags"])
```

This will print the following code:

```
print tags
# result: [[104, 65], [104, 65], [20, 30]]
```

What I want to achieve is to get an unique list of numbers. So that I end up with this situation:

```
# result [20,30,65,104]
```

In this case the double values are removed. Can someone help me to get into this direction?

Comment: So basically you're asking 2 questions (both asked here many times before):  1) [How to flatten a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) to one list of all elements. 2) [How to remove duplicates from that list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect you to research your problem before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way could be to use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to collect the different tags, maybe like this:

```
tag_set = set()
for index in data['words']: 
    count += 1
    for t in index["tags"]:
        # if the tag 't' already exists in 'tag_set', it will NOT
        # be added again, that is the built-in behavior of a set.
        tag_set.add(t)

print(len(tag_set))
print(list(sorted(tag_set)))
```

Comment: You can skip the second loop and just do `tag_set.update(index["tags"])`... Or a set-comp `tag_set = {t for index in data['words'] for t in index['tags']}`